# EWS: Contacts posted programmatically don't use the specified form

Tags: exchangewebservices, outlook-2010, ews-managed-api

Exchange Server 2010 SP3, Managed API 2.2, Outlook 2010: I have configured a subfolder of my Contacts folder to use a custom form. When I create contacts there manually, they are using my custom form. However, when the contacts are created programmatically into the subfolder, they appear to use the standard form.

How can I enforce all contacts to use my custom form?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to specify the contact's ItemClass property.

```
contact.ItemClass = "IPM.Contact.MyCustomForm";
```

My custom form is published in the Organizational Form Library.